# clear a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I get the first data from database and the listview will shown the data . At the moment, when the list is called more than once, the data is appended to the end of the list.

Is there a way to clear the listview so that the new data is again at the top of the listView

```
public class AndroidTestActivity extends Activity 
{
    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText tv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editView);
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                //http get
                try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.132/test.php");
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
                }

                //convert response to string
                try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

                    String line="0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    is.close();
                    result=sb.toString();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }

                //paring data
                int ct_id;
                String ct_name;        

                try{
                    jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    JSONObject json_data=null;  

                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ct_id=json_data.getInt("id");
                        ct_name=json_data.getString("name");
                        tv.append(ct_name);
                    }
                }catch(JSONException e1){
                //   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the array or `ArryList` of objects whatever you use in your `ListView Adapter`. Then load new data again to that `Array/ArrayList` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Call these two methods from the code where you want it to be clear
here adapter is a instance of your ArrayAdapter you are adding it in list.

```
adapter.clear()
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list each time and get your data from database in it and add the old data in this list only.

Answer (score 0):

Just Write `listView.setAdapter(null)`where you want to clear listview.. This worked for me..